# Solaris 10 - Find service attached to listening port

Tags: networking, solaris, netstat

I'm diagnosing an old Solaris 10 build and during port scans I've found an open port that's not on the approved list for this server.

I've tried various combinations of `netstat` switches but I can't seem to get the right output that gives me the associated service name or PID of the open port.

The feature set of netstat on this build seems to be limited compared to later solaris versions and other unix operating systems. `netstat -tulpn` for example doesn't work.

I also can't install `lsof` due to security restrictions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ironic that a security scan uncovers an issue that is made more difficult to resolve by a separate security restriction!

Comment: You're telling me! The environment is heavily restricted so I have to work with what's on the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Solaris you can use `pfiles <pid>` to see which network ports are opened by a certain process. Using a for-loop on `/proc/*` you can use `pfiles` on each running process to lookup the port you are after. Drawback is that you will need to be `root` on Solaris 10, or be able to become privileged (`pfexec pfiles`) on Solaris 11 to get the info.

If you are able to become `root` on the Solaris host you should be able to use something like:

```
PORT=22; for PID in /proc/*; do pfiles ${PID} |grep "port: ${PORT}" && echo ${PID}; done
```

This will iterate through `/proc/*`, filter for the specified port and if a match is found, the process ID (`/proc/####`) is shown on the next line.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I had to change the grep string slightly to include 2 space chars so ended up with "  port: ${PORT}"