# Checking server is listening without telnet, from CLI?

Tags: linux, osx, telnet

Typically an easy diagnostic approach to checking an application server is running is to run telnet again the host and port:

```
telnet somehost port
```

The issue is that some operating systems, such as macOS now make the tool unavailable by default. For this reason, instead of trying to see how to install telnet, I am curious to know if there are any other CLI approaches to check a server is listening, without needing special privileges?

Just to clarify I am looking for solutions that are as quick to use on any system as telnet, which is achievable in 5 seconds. Coding a solution doesn’t really offer a quick access approach.

Comment: Is Perl available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try several ways to check if something listen on particular port:

With `wget`/`curl`

```
wget your_IP:port
```

With `netstat`

```
netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep :port
```

With `lsof`

```
lsof -i :port
```

With `netcat`

```
nc -vz your_IP port
```

With `/proc` filesystem (probably will work only on linux)
([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298150/using-proc-pid-how-can-i-identify-a-network-port-numbers-application))

With `ss`

```
ss|grep LISTEN|grep :port
```

With `nmap`

```
nmap -sS -O -pport your_IP
```

**EDIT1** Also (almost) every ssh,http,ftp client can be used, but sometime will be hard to understand if port is closed by firewall or not available.
**EDIT2** Found in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43364744/2908599) sample way to use `cat` and `echo` to do the job:

```
true &>/dev/null </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/$PORT && echo open || echo closed
```

or with only `exec` command (if you do not see error port is open):

```
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/your_IP/port
```

And I found a way to use only `awk` to do the job (original [here](https://staaldraad.github.io/2017/12/20/netstat-without-netstat/)):

```
awk -v port=your_port 'function hextodec(str,ret,n,i,k,c){
    ret = 0
    n = length(str)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        c = tolower(substr(str, i, 1))
        k = index("123456789abcdef", c)
        ret = ret * 16 + k
    }
    return ret
}
function getIP(str,ret){
    ret=hextodec(substr(str,index(str,":")-2,2)); 
    for (i=5; i>0; i-=2) {
        ret = ret"."hextodec(substr(str,i,2))
    }
    ret = ret":"hextodec(substr(str,index(str,":")+1,4))
    return ret
} 
NR > 1 {{local=getIP($2);remote=getIP($3) }{ if (remote ~ "0:0" && local ~ ":"port) print local}}' /proc/net/tcp
```

**EDIT3** As mentioned in to comment some of the methods, especially based on `/dev` filesystem may bot work in your environment

**EDIT4** For Solaris I found [excellent Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316159/101265) which use `pfiles` to get open port.

Comment: you should mention explictily that `/dev/tcp/host/port` only works in `bash` (and `gawk`) and that it's something internal, completely fake (you cannot use  that path with external commands).

Comment: @mosvy, by fake, do you mean is local?

Comment: no, I mean that it's completely internal to bash, only bash and its builtin commands are able to use those paths. compare `cat </dev/tcp/localhost/smtp` to `cat /dev/tcp/localhost/smtp`

Comment: @mosvy, I added comment in to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, I [wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318441/117549) a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# tries to connect to the given IP and port (tcp)

use strict;
use IO::Socket;

my $desthost = shift or die "Usage: $0 host port\n";
my $destport = shift or die "Usage: $0 host port\n";

gethostbyname($desthost) || die "Invalid host given\n";

my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => $desthost,
        PeerPort => $destport,
        Proto    => 'tcp')
    or die "can't connect to $desthost:$destport: $!\n";
close $handle;
print "Success!\n"
```

It simulates a telnet connection (see the hard-coded `'tcp'`) and allows you to enter a hostname and port; it reports back success or failure based on the remote side answering (listening) at that port.

Comment: Coding a solution isn’t practical and doesn’t really offer a quick solution. The key is really to be able to use something readily available with the minimum effort.

Comment: It looks like it could become a one-liner quite easily.

Comment: If perl is available, copy-pasting this (after bookmarking if necessary) is not an unreasonable amount of effort. I've had to do worse...

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, really clever solution and it works as charm

Answer (score 2):

It's actually better not to use the `telnet` tool, which does more than just open a TCP socket, in certain circumstances trying to speak the TELNET protocol over the opened connection.  There are many tools that can be used to open a TCP socket, not least the client tools of all of the *other* TCP-based protocols, like FTP clients.  Again, like `telnet`, these can end up trying to speak their respective protocols after the connection opens.

For this very basic operation of making a TCP connection and immediately closing it, without attempting to speak any protocol over the connection, one does best to look at low-level tools.  `nc` is one, which I leave to other answers.  But others are the various [UCSPI-TCP and UCSPI-SSL](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/UCSPI.html) clients, whose job is *solely* to do exactly what you want: open the connection.  Just make the program that they then chain-load to do nothing except report the success.

- [`tcp-socket-connect`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-connect.xml) in [the nosh package](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/):

  ```
  tcp-socket-connect "${HOST}" "${PORT}" \
       sh -c 'echo Connected to ${TCPREMOTEIP}:${TCPREMOTEPORT} successfully.'
  ```

  This does both IPv4 and IPv6.
- the [`tcpclient`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/tcpclient.xml) in [the djbwares package](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/), a slightly polished version of Daniel J. Bernstein's original [`tcpclient`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpclient.html):

  ```
  tcpclient -H -R -l 0 "${HOST}" "${PORT}" \
       sh -c 'echo Connected to ${TCPREMOTEIP}:${TCPREMOTEPORT} successfully.'
  ```

  This only does IPv4, although a few patched versions exist that can also do IPv6.
- Laurent Bercot's [`s6-tcpclient`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpclient.html) from [s6-networking](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/):

  ```
  s6-tcpclient -N -H -R -l 0 "${HOST}" "${PORT}" \
       sh -c 'echo Connected to ${TCPREMOTEIP}:${TCPREMOTEPORT} successfully.'
  ```

  This does both IPv4 and IPv6.
- William Baxter's [`sslclient`](http://superscript.com/ucspi-ssl/sslclient.html):

  ```
  sslclient -H -R -l 0 "${HOST}" "${PORT}" \
       sh -c 'echo Connected to ${SSLREMOTEIP}:${SSLREMOTEPORT} successfully.'
  ```

  This negotiates SSL/TLS as well.  It only does IPv4, although Felix von Leitner publishes a patched version that does IPv6 too.

See the manual pages for details.  The options used here turn off various informational lookups about the endpoints that you do not need for a connectivity test.  The input host and port can be symbolic.  What is printed will be numeric.

These tools are portable, and can be built from source on a range of systems.  Indeed they are even pre-built and packaged as binaries for several operating systems, or available through ports, including but not limited to:

- [s6-networking for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/s6-networking-musl/)
- [Archnosh](https://github.com/tacatac/archnosh) and packages [for Debian Linux](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/debian-binary-packages.html), [for OpenBSD](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/openbsd-binary-packages.html), and [for FreeBSD](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/freebsd-binary-packages.html)
- ucspi-tcp [for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ucspi-tcp/),  [for Debian Linux](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/ucspi-tcp), [for Ubuntu Linux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ucspi-tcp), [in the FreeBSD ports tree](https://supernews.freshports.org/sysutils/ucspi-tcp/), [in the OpenBSD ports tree](http://ports.su/net/ucspi-tcp), [in the NetBSD packages collection](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/net/ucspi-tcp/README.html), and [in MacPorts](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/tree/master/net/ucspi-tcp)
- ucspi-ssl [in the FreeBSD ports tree](https://supernews.freshports.org/sysutils/ucspi-ssl/) and [in the NetBSD packages collection](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/net/ucspi-ssl/README.html)

Comment: My concern here is that these solutions aren’t  a 5 second check with a command line tool, which is the beauty of `telnet`.

Comment: Clearly that _is not_ the beauty of `telnet`, as `telnet` needs to be compiled/installed first on your system, as stated in the question.  Then there's the well-known fact that `telnet` speaks an actual protocol as pointed out.  Giving these commands a host and port, the only two inputs that they take and much the same as one would give `telnet`, _is_ a "5 second" job, furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

For checking remotely, nmap and nc are the goto tools, per Romeo's excellent answer. If you're on the server itself, FreeBSD and Ubuntu have the most excellent `sockstat` tool which is perfect:

`sockstat -p 80 -4 -6`